# How to get alias and column from string in java dynamically

Tags: java

How do I find alias and column name from strings dynamically so the
string format does not fix its changes according to condition. So the goal is to get strings having all possible chances which we can write in SQL WHERE Clause.

Example

1. `String MyString1="pro.itemDate<'2/02/2018'and pro.itemRate=0";`
2. `String MyString2="a.supplier_name='IBM'and a.offices=8;"`
3. `String MyString3="a.itm<>b.itm";`
4. `String MyString3="a.itm IN ('1','2')"`

Output

1. `pro.itemDate,pro.itemRate`
2. `a.supplier_name,a.offices;`
3. `a.itm,b.item;`
4. `a.itm;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to get all the matches

```
[^\s]+\.[^\s=]+
```

I assumed that you have strings like "pro.itemDate=<'2/02/2018'> and pro.itemRate=0"
and "a.supplier_name='IBM' AND a.offices=8"

Untested sample implementation in java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "pro.itemDate=<'2/02/2018'> and pro.itemRate=0";
      String pattern = "[^\\s]+\\.[^\\s=]+";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      while (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Edited to escape \ in the pattern

Comment: its Illegal escape character in string literal giving Error:(13, 37) java: illegal escape character

Comment: Replate the pattern like with String pattern = "[^\\s]+\\.[^\\s=]+";

Comment: thanks its working

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: a.itm<>b.itm for this condition its giving issue when their is no space

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.split("and ");` to get 2 seperate strings. (notice that there is a space).

// You may have to use `String.split("ADN ")`;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split 2 times searching for "and" or "AND" in first split or use regular expresions:

```
String MyString1="pro.itemDate=<'2/02/2018'>and pro.itemRate=0";
String[] result1 = null;
String[] result2 = null;
String[] result = MyString1.split("and ");
if(result.length == 2 )
{
    result1 = result[0].split("=");
    result2 = result[1].split("=");
}
System.out.println(result1[0]+"\t"+result2[0]);
```

Comment: but i  need output pro.itemDate,pro.itemRate

Comment: In my case it works like that, and what's in yours? Have you tried my code?